# Overloading operator whose parameter is not class or enum

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, fractions

I want to overload operator like this:

```
fraction operator / (int a, int b) // error here
{
return fraction(a,b);
}
```

(Not inside fraction class).
But the compiler says:

```
[Error] 'fraction operator/(int, int)' must have an argument of class or enumerated type.
```

Can I get around this? (Just want when I write like 1/3 to convert into `fraction(1,3)` not `fraction(1/3)` (1/3 which equal 0.3333333 in float so when converting back into fraction, I will get 16666667/50000000, not 1/3)

Comment: The standard only permits overriding operators that can accept at least one non-fundamental type - and `int` is a fundamental type.  There are various reasons for this (e.g. preventing changing the fact that dividing two arguments of type `int` always gives a result of type `int`) .   Permitted overloads, since `fraction` is not a fundamental type, include an `operator/(int, fraction)`, an `operator/(fraction, int)` [or a member of `fraction` of the form `operator/(int)`], and an `operator/(fraction, fraction)`.  You can use combinations of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to overload operator like this:
>
> ```
> fraction operator / (int a, int b) // error here
> ```

You may not do what you want, as the compiler says.

> Can I get around this?

Want something else. There's no way to change division of two `int` in C++.

You can just write `fraction(1, 3)`. If you would like something shorter to write, then you could use a user defined literal: `1_frac / 3`.

---

> not fraction(1/3) (1/3 which equal 0.3333333 in float so when converting back into fraction

1/3 is not a float. It equals 0.

Comment: You might want to say explicitly that `1/3` gives a result of type `int`.    What you said is correct, but only obvious to people who understand that `1/3` gives a result of type `int` in C++ - it is not obvious to someone who thinks `1/3` can give whatever result one wants - including the OP in this case.

Comment: 1/3 is not a float but like (float) 1/3 or 1.0/3.0 is what I meant.